# PHP - show 'echo' one time in for loop

Tags: php

Today i'am using PHP DOMDocument class to find all link's in source code. 
$links array have all links from site. Function 'for' use loop iteration for find given $domain.

```
echo 'Find link: ' . $domain . '';
echo "<b>Status: ";

//$links is array with all links
//$domain is domain for example : http://example.com

for($i = 0;$i<count($links);$i++)
        {
            $find_href = preg_match("@$domain@i", $links[$i]['href']);

            if($find_href)
            {

                    if($links[$i]['href'] != "")
                    {
                        echo $links[$i]['anchor'];
                        echo 'Link found';'
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Link not found';
                    }
```

Example:

searched domain: http: //example.com
searched url: http: //www.iana.org

Result:

```
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
http://www.iana.org/domains/example
Link found  // find bacouse link is in source code of http://example.com
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
```

searched domain: http://example.com 
searched link: http://google.com

Result:

```
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
Link not found
```

If $domain not found in $links array, How to print one time "Link not found" ?

Comment: do you want to stop you loop if not found ? or just print only one time this message for X iteration ?

Comment: What is the output of print_r($links), need only a sample output

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your attention

Comment: You are most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply register a found condition in a variable and then output the not found messages after the loop is complete based on whether you found something.

```
echo 'Find link: ' . $domain . '';
echo "<b>Status: ";

//$links is array with all links
//$domain is domain for example : http://example.com

$found = false;

for($i = 0;$i<count($links);$i++) {
    $find_href = preg_match("@$domain@i", $links[$i]['href']);

    if($find_href) {

        if($links[$i]['href'] != "") {
            echo $links[$i]['anchor'];
            echo 'Link found';
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo 'Link not found';
}
```

Picking up on the comments received this would be better code

```
echo 'Find link: ' . $domain . '';
echo "<b>Status: ";

//$links is array with all links
//$domain is domain for example : http://example.com

$found = false;

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $find_href = preg_match("@$domain@i", $link['href']);

    if($find_href) {
        if($link['href'] != '') {
            echo $link['anchor'] . "\nLink found";
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo 'Link not found';
}
```

Comment: just a small hint: better `count($links)` before the for-loop, not inside it. This way it would count several times instead of only 1 time. Just a small performance-thing

Comment: @DasSaffe Yea true. Didnt want to change too much of the original code and confuse the OP

Comment: Even better would be to use `foreach()` instead of `for`.

Comment: @Barmar Yea ditto the confusion thing

Comment: @DasSaffe Amended as per Barmar's suggestion

Comment: @Barmar Amended as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Every time the for loop does + 1 with the variable '$i'. Make a variable '$total' and count the '$links' and then in the for loop you just do:

```
<!-- above the for loop -->
$total = count($links);  

<!-- in the for loop -->
if ($i == $total) {
    echo 'Link not found';
}
```